# Centos freeing up disk space

Tags: centos, terminal, disk-usage

I have a CentOS server running Plesk and it's run out of space on the plesk partition. I have narrowed down where a lot of the disk space is being used, but I'm not sure how to move forward. Can I redirect the folder elsewhere or is it reasonably safe to resize the partition?

#### Output of df -l

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              4956284   4803960         0 100% /
/dev/sda3              4956316   2861496   1838988  61% /var
/dev/sda2            461065932  97508992 339758252  23% /home
/dev/sda1                77749     17882     55853  25% /boot
tmpfs                   978504         0    978504   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   978504         0    978504   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-local
tmpfs                   978504         0    978504   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue
tmpfs                   978504         0    978504   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-remote
tmpfs                   978504      1900    976604   1% /usr/local/psa/handlers/info
tmpfs                   978504         0    978504   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/spool
```

#### Output of du -sh * on the root

```
12K     aquota.user
7.8M    bin
12M     boot
168K    dev
49M     etc
93G     home
222M    lib
27M     lib64
16K     lost+found
8.0K    media
0       misc
8.0K    mnt
0       net
99M     opt
0       proc
96M     root
35M     sbin
8.0K    selinux
8.0K    srv
0       sys
44K     tmp
4.6G    usr
2.7G    var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `du -sh` on `/usr` and `/root` to see if your `/root` is not filled with some useless files or if on `/usr` you can de-install some program you not use.

You can use `gParted` to expand your partition, it's safe normaly.

Comment: `/root` contains 96MB, and `/usr` 4.6GB (which is not exactly lightweight, but hardly excessive either depending on what software is installed).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I followed it down the rabbit hole and /usr/local/psa is using 3.2GB is it safe to remove anything within this?

Comment: Apparently `/usr/local/psa` is the Plesk directory. Dig into it again. See if you can clear cache or something like with Plesk (don't know it really). Else you can move `/usr/local/psa` into `/home` but I think you need to do it from a live CD (without launching Plesk).

Comment: Hello again Hugo, its split between mainly two folders, cgitory and apspkgarc though I am not familiar with the back end of Plesk to know what they are used for. Alternatively can you recommend a good walkthrough as to how to increase the partition size (and I am assuming shrinking SDA2 to cover the space requirements)? thanks again

Comment: Frem GUI, use  `gParted` as I said. You just have to drag bound to expand partition. But you need to do this without mounting the partition. So do it from a [live cd](http://www.sysresccd.org). Or you can do it from command line like explained for ext3 [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions).

Comment: Ah okay, that makes it a little more complicated. I am logged into it via SSH as its a virtualized machine at another location. What would you say is the best course of action? Thanks again.

Comment: Make something like this (I'm not responsible if something goes wrong with Plesk, I don't know of it works really) : 
`/etc/init.d/psa stop && mkdir ~/.psa && mv /usr/local/psa/* ~/.psa/ && rmdir /usr/local/psa && ln -s ~/.psa /usr/local/psa && /etc/init.d/psa start`

Comment: Thanks Hugo! I ended up removing backup.tar.gz, locale and documentation files but I will have to see about implementing your solution to stop it from happening again in future. Unfortunately I have given myself a bigger headache from this but I will post the problem in a new thread. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command on your terminal

```
find / -type f -size +500000k -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

This will list all files greater than 500 MB from root

Check if any `.log` files or core dump files are there that you don't need and delete it.

Comment: While this is useful information it doesn't really address the question asked by OP about moving the mount or resizing.